# Infinite multiplication of the fractions of square roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to show
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\cdots=\frac{2}{\pi}
$$
I have no clue on this. I am very appreciated if someone can help me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula

Comment: This is exactly Viete's formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\sqrt{2}=2\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$, using the formular $1+\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2
\theta $ and $\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos \theta$

The left side is exactly the limit of

$$\frac{1}{2^n\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}.$$